# Windows service and mingw

Tags: c++, windows-services, mingw

Is there possibility to compile windows service using only mingw c++ compiler and library?

I assume that it is possible to use compiler with Visual Studio standard library and means, but want to do to this almost fully opensourced.

Any experience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you can build programs with the Windows Platform SDK (or whatever it's called today) using MinGW, you can build Win32 services.

Services are just Win32 programs with some specific protocols used to register them with the system and interact with the operating system's service controller.

Comment: The platform SDK contains the compiler used in Visual Studio. Doing it directly with MinGW is going to be difficult because MinGW's unicode support is lacking. If you can work around the patchy support there then there should be no reason you can't use MinGW though.

Comment: FYI: I have ported the Complete Service Example code from microsoft to mingw / gcc and documented it here: https://xpra.org/trac/ticket/1527#comment:4